# What's The Ruby Community's Preferred Type of Loop?

Tags: ruby

Self teaching myself Python, I've taken a Computer Science class that taught in Java. I've noticed that for loops are the gold standard for each language. Yet prowling around this website and other tutortials, the for loop is no where to be found, despite it being in Ruby and, (in my opinion) it's pretty straight forward and well known syntax. Whats wrong with for loops?

Since Ruby offers a plethora of ways to accomplish a task, which type of loop is the most popular and why?

Comment: `.map`, `each` or other array/enumerator methods based on actual purpose. `loop do end` for loops not which not involves sequence of objects

Comment: Read the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide). Understand that the guide is merely opinion, and this question is about opinions, which is explicitly listed in [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), so I have voted to close this question. Additionally, you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and carefully proofread your question and its title before submitting it.

Comment: That is a really poor thing to do considering I explicitly asked why for loops aren't used and then asked for an explanation, like the stack overflow rules encourage (ie, "However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK."). It's a straight forward question that other people new to Ruby and migrating from other languages can benefit from. Their must be a conclusive answer to versus here say opinion. Are you saying that Ruby users flippantly decided to not use for loops and its the way it is just because and its foolish to question it?

Answer (score 3):

Ruby is unusual in that you really do not ever use `for`. There's always a better tool for the job. For example:

```
n.times do |i|
  # for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) in other languages
end

10.upto(20) do |i|
  # for (i = 10; i < 20; ++i) in other languages
end

a = [ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ]
a.each do |v|
  # for (v in a) in other languages
end

a = [ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ]
a.map do |v|
  # .map(v => ...) in JavaScript
end
```

The [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html) module is the source of a lot of Ruby's power because it's available on things like Hash, Array, and others, as well as things that can be easily converted to those things, which is an even bigger list of options.

What's a complex problem to solve in other languages is often a few simple transformations in Ruby and nary a `for` loop.

An important property of Enumerable methods is that these often emit an [Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html) which can be used to chain operations together, like this:

```
10.upto(20).with_index.map do |i, j|
  # Provides pairs like [ 10, 0 ], [ 11, 1 ], etc.
  i + j
end
```

Where that provides both a value, an index, and a way of converting or combining those into a subsequent result which itself can be iterated, altered, or otherwise transformed.

Comment: The final sentence is so true. Ruby is graceful and elegant when other, more popular, languages are like tripping over my feet and make me want to gouge my eyes out.

Comment: @theTinMan When working in JavaScript all we have is Lodash and memories of what Ruby could have done for us instead. In other languages we don't even have that!

Comment: Perhaps explain *why* `for` loops are not used. All the methods you mention use blocks, but `for` loops don't. Therefore, local variables created within `for` loops are visible beyond the end of the loop.  That's not the case with blocks.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: That's not really a reason. It is a _difference_, but since I'll rather write `x = nil; foo.each { ... }` to make sure `x` is available in the block (and will survive after it) than use `for`, it proves that it's not a decision point for me for or against `for`. I think one is consistency and chainability of the block form. It is super easy to change `each` into `map` or `inject` or `detect` or whatever else, or to add a second step afterwards. Another is the knowledge that `for` is using `#each` under the hood anyway, might as well write it directly.

Comment: @Amadan, as you say, if you want a (local) variable used in a block to be visible after leaving the block, it must be defined before entering the block. I was speaking of the opposite: variables created in the block are not visible after leaving the block--a good thing--but that is not the case with `for` loops. `for` loops  do not use a block and therefore do not change the scope; variables created in a `for` loop remain visible to prying eyes after exiting the loop. The same argument applies to using `loop` (which takes a block) rather than `while` or `until` loops.